# How to add a tag when messages is multiline in Logstash

Tags: logstash, filebeat, logstash-file

I use Filebeat6x to ship my logs to logstash.
Some of my logs may be a multiline thats why I use Filebeat to [Manage multiline messages](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.4/multiline-examples.html)

Now I want to add filter in logstash to do something like

> if the message is multiline then add tag.

If the parsing of those multilines was from logstash I will use [multliline_tag](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/plugins-codecs-multiline.html#plugins-codecs-multiline-multiline_tag).

But how can I tag those multilines when the parsing is done in filebeat?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?